# Passing .NET objects via COM interop using Delphi and the JCL .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com, interop

I am basically trying to do:

[Passing strongly typed arguments in .NET COM interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793844/passing-strongly-typed-arguments-in-net-com-interop)

But using Delphi and JCL to do it.  I am admittedly NOT a COM guru and have done searches but can't quite find an answer to what I am trying to do.  I have C# with this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Example1ClassLibrary
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Example1
    {
        public Example1Obj AddByObj(Example1Obj Obj)
        {
            var ret = new Example1Obj();
            ret.XVal = AddFunction(Obj.XVal, Obj.YVal);
            ret.YVal = 0;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Example1Obj
    {
        public int XVal;
        public int YVal;
    }
}
```

And Delphi:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Host := TJclClrHost.Create('v4.0.30319');
  Host.Start();
  Obj := Host.DefaultAppDomain.CreateInstance('Example1ClassLibrary', 'Example1ClassLibrary.Example1').UnWrap();
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pass: OleVariant;
  Ret: OleVariant;
begin
  Pass := Host.DefaultAppDomain.CreateInstance('Example1ClassLibrary', 'Example1ClassLibrary.Example1Obj').UnWrap();
  Pass.XVal := StrToInt(EditX.text);
  Pass.YVal := StrtoInt(EditY.text);
  Ret := Obj.AddByObj(Pass);
  EditResult.Text := Ret.XVal;
end;
```

When I click `Button4`, I get the

> EOleSysError "The parameter is incorrect".

at the line:

```
Ret := Obj.AddByObj(Pass);
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, what am I missing.  Note: Simple types works fine so actually loading the assembly, creating the object, and calling a method with simple types works great.

Comment: Am I missing something? How can this work unless you use COM? Where are the C# interfaces? What led you to this solution? And why do you need JCL? What's wrong with CoCreateObject?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is COM interop, but if it helps the OP's source code appears to come from [this article](http://adamjohnston.me/2013/04/14/delphi-dotnet-interop-with-jvcl/) about .Net interop with the JVCL.

Comment: My understanding is that CoCreateObject requires the assembly to be in the GAC which I do not want.  This example loads the assembly from the app directory.  That is what JclDotNet unit affords me and why I was wanting to use it.  And yes, I did build my example off the article that David M pointed out.

Comment: To add further, the only reason I mentioned COM was because of the ComVisible requirement, that it is late binding, and that I am receiving an OLE error.  Perhaps I am overextending the reach of the term COM because I don't really know what is going on under the JCL hood, but the Delphi side is behaving as it does when I've worked with COM objects in the past.